# How to read/understand the nested ternary values in a json object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to decipher someone else's code and have trouble understanding this json object with  nested ternary values for each key. Please help me understand/read this code :

QUESTION: How do you read this (which part of if/else gets assigned when and how?)

```
let permissions = {
    view: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false,
    create: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.create) ? 
      currentRole.create.includes(title) : false : false,
    edit: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.edit) ? 
      currentRole.edit.includes(title) : false : false,
    all: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.all) ? 
      currentRole.all.includes(title) : false : false,
  }
```

Here is how currentRole is defined

```
const UserContext = createContext({
  authenticated: false, profile: null
});
const [userState, setUserState] = useContext(UserContext);
const currentRole = userState.currentRole;
```

Please help me understand how to read the if/else part of the json key: value pair.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you understand what ternary operator is. if not have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator.

Lets breakdown the permission part.

```js
let permissions = {
    view: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false,
    create: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.create) ? 
      currentRole.create.includes(title) : false : false,
    edit: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.edit) ? 
      currentRole.edit.includes(title) : false : false,
    all: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.all) ? 
      currentRole.all.includes(title) : false : false,
  }
```

and focus on

```js
const view = currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false;
```

where we can think of it as

```js
const view = currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      (currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false);
```

i.e. if `currentRole` is evaluate to true, then

```js
const view = Array.isArray(currentRole.view);
```

otherwise,

```js
const view = currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false;
```

Not sure if it clears your question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Given one of the nested ternary expressions

```
currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
  currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false
```

The order of precedence is left to right, or when properly formatted

```
currentRole
  ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view)
    ? currentRole.view.includes(title)
    : false
  : false;
```

It is now easier to see by the index depth what values go with what ternary operator.

An equivalent snippet using if-else blocks would be

```
if (currentRole) {
  if (Array.isArray(currentRole.view)) {
    return currentRole.view.includes(title);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} else {
  return false
}
```

This is redundant though with two logic branches returning the same value, can be simplified to

```
if (currentRole && Array.isArray(currentRole.view)) {
  return currentRole.view.includes(title);
} else {
  return false
}
```

or

```
currentRole && Array.isArray(currentRole.view)
  ? currentRole.view.includes(title)
  : false;
```

or even more simply (credit to @cars10m!) which completely removes ternary operators

```
currentRole &&
  Array.isArray(currentRole.view) &&
  currentRole.view.includes(title);
```

Each conditional test needs to resolve truthy to continue processing the expression, with the result of the final test being the value returned.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a further explanation - @Drew Reese has already done a great job on it - but yet another short way of creating the JSON:

```js
let currentRole={edit:['game'],all:['comments']},
    title='game';

let res="view,create,edit,all".split(',').reduce((a,c)=> 
   (a[c] = currentRole            
        && Array.isArray(currentRole[c])            
        && currentRole[c].includes(title),a), {});

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Oh, mental gymnastics a little more involved, but I do enjoy the complete removal of ternaries altogether.

Comment: Yeah, I know, probably a little "over the top" but it is an exewrcise in mental gymnastics! :D

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operations:

Lets take an example :

```
condition ? trueResult : falseResult
```

Is equivalent to:

```
if(condition)
{
return trueResult
}
else{
return falseResult
}
```

Another one

```
condition1? return1
:conditions? return2
:conditions?return3
```

is similar as

```
if(condition1){

return return1

}elseif(condition2){

return return2

}elseif(condition3){

return return3

}
```

Another one

```
condition1 ? condition2 ? return1:return2:return3
```

is equivalent to :

```
if(condition1){

if(condition2){

return return1

}else{

return return2

}

}else{

return return3

}
```

Likewise in your condition

```
 view: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false,
```

Is equivalent to

```
if(currentRole){

if(Array.isArray(currentRole.view){

return currentRole.view.includes(title)

}else{

return false

}}else{

return false

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with a simple ternary operator
For example,

```
a == b ? console.log(a) : console.log(b);
```

Here, if a == b condition true then it execute first statement console.log(a)
Otherwise, second statement execute console.log(b).

**Thumb Rule: Always start to read a ternary operator from LHS to RHS.**

Let's start with your code.

```
let permissions = {
    view: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false,
    create: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.create) ? 
      currentRole.create.includes(title) : false : false,
    edit: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.edit) ? 
      currentRole.edit.includes(title) : false : false,
    all: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.all) ? 
      currentRole.all.includes(title) : false : false,
  }
```

Let's read the view key from the permissions object

```
view: currentRole ? Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? 
      currentRole.view.includes(title) : false : false
```

Let's export this ternary operator:

1. condition: before the question mark(?).  `currentRole` is the condition in your case.
2. First Statement: After the first question mark(?) and before the last colon(:)

   `Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ? currentRole.view.includes(title) : false`

   This is the first statement in your case.
3. Second Statement: After the last colon(:) `false` is your second statement in your case

Now let's think about just a simple ternary operator.

If the condition true then First Statement will execute Otherwise Second statement will execute.
In your case,

1. Let's assume that `currentRole` is true then

   First Statement `Array.isArray(currentRole.view) ?currentRole.view.includes(title) : false` will execute.
   Now treat this First Statement as ternary operator again!
   Whatever value return from this turnary operator will be the value of the `view key`
2. Let's assume that `currentRole` is false then Second Statement `false` will execute. So `view key` value will be `false`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the author of the code intended for `view`, `create`, `edit` and `all` to always be false unless `currentRole.view`, `currentRole.create`, etc. were defined as true in a database, probably. But then sometimes they needed to make an exception to that for testing certain `titles`. And when they needed to test a `title` they would add that to the array *and change the first operator before the colon to true*. That would let them test a certain specific title as how it would look when it was editable... probably without being logged into the system. They have all those as false so there's no reason for this logic except for them to test individual titles without tripping the whole system into making everything editable.

This looks like production code that's being tested on. Keeping all the ternary values as false is a safety mechanism just in case. TL;DR there is no reason for all that extra logic except to test a certain `title`.